# How to access multiple collections of data in a single background worker instance

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have this form where I perform many operations on the database. I'm fetching a huge list of products and suppliers from the database. Now I am able to successfully implement background worker for list of  products but I can't get the list of suppliers in the same background thread.

It gives me invocation exception. Is it possible to get multiple lists in single background thread?

```
public void GetDetails()
{
      BackgroundWorker worker = new  BackgroundWorker(); 
      worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;          
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=worker_RunWorkerCompleted; 
     IsBusy = true;       
     worker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}
  private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  { 
           ObservableCollection Products = (ObservableCollection)e.Result; 
         foreach (var prod in Products) 
          { 
                 this.Products.Add(prod); 
           }   
          IsBusy = false; 
     } 

      private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
   { 
            ObservableCollection Products = new ObservableCollection();        

            ObservableCollection Supplier = new ObservableCollection(); 
             using (Genesis_DataDataContext dataDc = new Genesis_DataDataContext()) 
             { 
                   foreach (tbl_Product thisProduct in dataDc.tbl_Products) 
                   { 
                         Products.Add(thisProduct); 
                    }
                     //foreach (tbl_Supplier thisSupplier in dataDc.tbl_Suppliers) 
                    //{
                           // Suppliers.Add(thisSupplier); 
                     //} 
              } 
        e.Result = Products;
    }
```

Comment: Please Post error message and stack trace.

Comment: Please also post sample code. The answer to your question is "yes" but we can help without more information.

Comment: This is the part where I fetch data using background worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your **Genesis_DataDataContext()** is producing, but you might be able to just create a basic class to load your data in:

```
class BasicClass {

  public ObservableCollection Products { get; set; }

  public ObservableCollection Suppliers { get; set; }

}
```

Now, with something like that, you could pass both data items back in the same object.

```
    public void GetDetails2()
    {
        using (var worker = new BackgroundWorker())
        {
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                var w = (BackgroundWorker)s;
                var bc = new BasicClass();
                bc.Products = new ObservableCollection();
                bc.Suppliers = new ObservableCollection();
                using (var dataDc = new Genesis_DataDataContext())
                {
                    // dbl_Products may use a Data Reader, so use an index.
                    // This may or may not produce an error, depending on how the Genesis_DataDataContext is designed.
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataDc.tbl_Products.Count; i++) {
                        w.ReportProgress(i + 1, dataDc.tbl_Products.Count);
                        var item = dataDc.tbl_Products[i];
                        bc.Products.Add(item);
                    }
                    w.ReportProgress(-1, "On to Suppliers.")
                    // dbl_Products may use a Data Reader, so use an index.
                    // This may or may not produce an error, depending on how the Genesis_DataDataContext is designed.
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataDc.tbl_Suppliers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        w.ReportProgress(i + 1, dataDc.tbl_Suppliers.Count);
                        var item = dataDc.tbl_Suppliers[i];
                        bc.Suppliers.Add(item);
                    }
                    e.Result = bc;
                }
            };
            worker.ProgressChanged += delegate (object s, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    var index = e.ProgressPercentage;
                    var state = e.UserState.ToString();
                    int total;
                    if (int.TryParse(state, out total))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} of {1}", index, total);
                    } else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(state);
                    }
                } else
                {
                    worker.CancelAsync();
                }
            };
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    var bc = e.Result as BasicClass;
                    foreach (var item in bc.Products)
                    {
                        this.Products.Add(item);
                    }
                    foreach (var item in bc.Suppliers)
                    {
                        this.Suppliers.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            IsBusy = worker.IsBusy;
        }

    }
```

I take it **IsBusy** is another variable you created. I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: That datacontext is a autogenerated linq file.I access database data from that data context